# keeping terraform state file in S3\\bucket when deploying kube using kops / terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform

I am deploying a kube cluster using kops/terraform. My Kube's state store in in S3. However I also want to save my the terraform state file to be in S3:\bucket\something.tf instead of a local filesystem from where I deploy the kube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Kops with terraform, the result is the usual terraform definition. Simply your own in the same folder to modify/augment what kops generated. To achieve what you need a section like

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "mybucket"
    key    = "path/to/my/key"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}
```

should be enough. For reference : https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/s3.html